# uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found

Tags: php, ckeditor, yii2, yii-widgets

I have installed **CKEditor** widget from [yii2-ckeditor-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) using composer. Install was successful, there was no error.

Here is my view file:

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;

.....

<?php echo $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'basic'
]) ?>
```

when I see in browser, there is nothing in the place of **CKEditor** in the form. I checked console message in **firebug** I found this.

[image]

while without CKEditor it is working fine

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea(['rows'=>6]) ?>
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I posted this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/24) and here is what I got:

> It seems that your issue is related to the assets registration.

I do not know what is the issue with asset registration? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was problem with asset registration. I `Kdiff` current asset directory with another projects asset directory. And there was files missing I copied them in current project and now its running fine.

Comment: Yes this is right.  Just look in the base \ckeditor directory and make sure the files from here are in your script directory

Comment: In my case I emptied both my "frontend\web\assets" and "backend\web\assets", and then it worked fine again, could be a caching problem too

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem, I managed to solve this by making a hard copy of the assets in the web folder.

```
$ php app/console assets:install
```

> For more info check:
>   [Symfony 2.6: Smarter assets:install command](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command)